# C# Terminal Services Aware Application

Tags: c#, .net, terminal-services

I'm thinking about creating an application (or refactoring other in-house software) which could work effectively on a TS server (which from my knowledge means that every instance shares the core code/data in memory). Does the .NET framework actually support it or would I need to use some technique/technology/toolkit?

Comment: Each user session on a terminal server is entirely isolated. Each user instance of your application will be completely separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to run under Terminal Services.
Just make sure that your program can run under multiple users simultaneously, and that it looks good at lower color depths.

Comment: Well yes of course but then every instance will load the whole thing and each needed .NET assembly - in other words it's going to hog up the memory. I was rather thinking of avoiding that.

Comment: @hyp: Give your assemblies strong names and place them in the GAC.  I'm not 100% sure this will work across TS connections, but its your only option.  Other than prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @Will: didn't know about GAC - that's a good suggestion, will look more into it. Thanks

Comment: @hyp: Gac'd assemblies [can be loaded into memory once and shared across appdomains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx#S6).  This is probably limited to each process, but I don't know 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is possible, but perhaps you can try to ensure that only one instance of your application is running system-wide and from within you're code, try to seperate different user-instances. Can anyone elaborate on this?